# How can I post new youtube videos from any channel on my wordpress blog?

Tags: youtube, wordpress, youtube-api

I keep track of many youtube channels for my blog audience and I would like to add new videos from many different channels as a post automatically.

There are many plugins but nothing seems to work? Im assuming because of some changes in Youtube API

Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

When YouTube went to version 3.0 the older version was deprecated and many plugins did not update so no longer work. I currently use Video Blogster Pro for my sites.